# batch file keeps repeating the set /p statement

Tags: batch-file

I'm write a batch file to try to do stuff. like as an assistant or something. so I'm starting off with changing the colour but I can't even get to that because the set /p statement keeps repeating its self.

```
@echo off
title Edmond
set "action="
goto :aCheck
:aPrompt
set /p "action=What shall I do for you master?"
:aCheck
if not defined a goto :aPrompt
echo %a%


if /i "%action%" == "color" (
    echo stuff
    :cl
    set /p BC=What Should the background color be?
    set /p FC=and the foreground color?

    if %BC%==Black (
        set BC1=0
    ) else if %BC%==Blue (
        set BC1=1
    ) else if %BC%==Green (
        set BC1=2
    ) else if %BC%==Aqua (
        set BC1=3
    ) else if %BC%==Red (
        set BC1=4
    ) else if %BC%==Purple (
        set BC1=5
    ) else if %BC%==Yellow (
        set BC1=6
    ) else if %BC%==White (
        set BC1=7
    ) else if %BC%==Gray (
        set BC1=8
    ) else if %BC%==LBlue (
        set BC1=9
    ) else if %BC%==LGreen (
        set BC1=a
    ) else if %BC%==LAqua (
        set BC1=b
    ) else if %BC%==LRed (
        set BC1=c
    ) else if %BC%==LPurple (
        set BC1=d
    ) else if %BC%==LYellow (
        set BC1=e
    ) else if %BC%==LWhite (
        set BC1=f
    ) else (
        echo I'm sorry, I didn't exactly understand that.
        echo By any chance could you say it again?
        goto cl
    )

    if %FC%==Black (
        set FC1=0
    ) else if %FC%==Blue (
        set FC1=1
    ) else if %FC%==Green (
        set FC1=2
    ) else if %FC%==Aqua (
        set FC1=3
    ) else if %FC%==Red (
        set FC1=4
    ) else if %FC%==Purple (
        set FC1=5
    ) else if %FC%==Yellow (
        set FC1=6
    ) else if %FC%==White( 
        set FC1=7
    ) else if %FC%==Gray (
        set FC1=8
    ) else if %FC%==LBlue (
        set FC1=9
    ) else if %FC%==LGreen (
        set FC1=a
    ) else if %FC%==LAqua (
        set FC1=b
    ) else if %FC%==LRed (
        set FC1=c
    ) else if %FC%==LPurple (
        set FC1=d
    ) else if %FC%==LYellow (
        set FC1=e
    ) else if %FC%==LWhite (
        set FC1=f
    ) else (
        echo I'm sorry, I didn't exactly understand that.
    )
    echo Applying changes.
    ping localhost -n 2 >nul
    color %FC%%BC%
) else (
    echo I'm sorry, I didn't exactly understand that.
)
pause
exit
```

does someone mind helping me?

Comment: `if not defined a goto :aPrompt` - where do you define `a`? If you don't define it, the check for `defined a` will always be false and will return to `:aPrompt`. You probably mean to check for `if not defined action` instead.

Comment: so what should I do (kind of started on tuesday)

Comment: I just told you that - see what I wrote about what you probably meant to check in my last comment.

Comment: okay then I''l try it out

Comment: now it says ( was unexpected at this time

Comment: I can't see what you've done now, because it's not on my screen.

Comment: okay now i've edited the original post. can you tell me whats wrong doctor? (thought like being witty if it qualifies)

Comment: I don't see an `action a` in what I wrote before. Where did you get it? Read what I wrote again in my first comment.

Comment: no I tryed to fix the problem of it flashing on the screen with a thing I found on reddit and forgot to change a to action. but not it still flashes on my screen and seems to say (if I can print screen at the right time) 'a' is not an internal or external command. ECHO is off. ( was unexpected at this time

Comment: I've told you twice to **remove** `a` - does repeating it a third time help? See my answer; it's clear you're not reading what I'm writing here.

Comment: I rolled back your edit, because your original question was answered. If you have a new question, start a new post and ask it there. You cannot change the question after it's been answered, because that invalidates the answers that have been posted.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an invalid test in `if not defined` (both with the `a` you originally posted, as you didn't define `a`, and with the code you currently have posted based on my comment where you test for `if not defined action a`).

You need to test for `if not defined action`, as demonstrated here (I've added a `pause` that wasn't in your original code so you can see whether it gets past the test or not - test it both by not entering a value and then by entering one).

```
@echo off
title Edmond
set "action="
goto :Check
:Prompt
set /p "action=What shall I do for you master?"
:Check
if not defined action goto :Prompt
echo %action%
pause
```

Comment: now it says 'a' is not a recognized internal or external command, operable program or batch file. ECHO os off. and after pause it exits

Comment: saying ( was unexpected at this time

Comment: There is no `a` in what I posted here, which means you didn't use it. **If you're not going to pay attention to the answers, why did you post here???**

Comment: wait I got rid of the 'a' problem. I left it in, in one point

Comment: BECAUSE I HAVE A HARD TIME PAYING ATTENTION BECAUSE OF ADHD

Comment: But you're wasting both my time and yours here. I'm sorry you're dealing with ADHD, but you need to concentrate here. (AND IT'S RUDE TO SHOUT, so please don't do so.)

Comment: I've just spent more than half an hour trying to do so, but I mind when you're not using the help I'm providing. I've answered the question you asked here. If you now have a different question, start a new post and ask the question there. You can't change the entire meaning of the question after you've received answers to it.